# How can I start a midlet automatically at a specific time?

Tags: java-me, push, midlet

I want to use the Push registry to start the midlet at a specified time. When I run the app, even when the time is exceeded the midlet is not started..

public void startApp() {

```
    System.out.println( "AlarmMIDlet: startApp" );

    try {
        Date    now = new Date();
        long    previous;
                    String cn = this.getClass().getName();
                    System.out.println("Class name : "+cn);
        previous    = PushRegistry.registerAlarm( "hello.AlarmMIDlet", now.getTime() + 600 );

        System.out.println( "AlarmMIDlet: time of previous alarm: " + previous );
    } catch ( java.lang.ClassNotFoundException cnf ) {
        System.out.println( "AlarmMIDlet: Class not Found" );
    } catch ( javax.microedition.io.ConnectionNotFoundException connnf ) {
        System.out.println( "AlarmMIDlet: Connection Not Found" );
    }

    System.out.println( "AlarmMIDlet: startApp: return" );

    notifyDestroyed();
}
```

Anyone has ever faced a similar problem?How to sort this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be fair I never used PushRegistry, but from what I read you need to schedule time alarm on the middlet destroyApp(). Have look at this article, scroll down for [Registering a Timer Alarm](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/pushreg/)

Comment: I've used same example in the codes I've posted in my question